# How to correct the "exception in Tkinter callback" error in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is my code:

```
#Game Restart Func 

def restart_program():
    for widget in root.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    button = Button(root, text='Stop', width=25, command=root.destroy)
    button.pack()

    b1 = Button(root, text="Restart", command=restart_program)
    b1.pack()

    g = GalagaGame(root)
    root.after(10, g.gameLoop())
    root.mainloop()
```

This function is a function to restart the game
And the main function was written like this

```
root = Tk()

button = Button(root, text='Stop', width=25, command=root.destroy)
button.pack()

b1 = Button(root, text="Restart", command=restart_program)
b1.pack()

g = GalagaGame(root)
root.after(10, g.gameLoop())
root.mainloop()
```

But there are still strange errors.

Exception in Tkinter callback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kim Donguk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)

  File "C:\Users\Kim Donguk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 745, in callit
    func(*args)

  File "C:\Users\Kim Donguk\Desktop\Game project\game_source\game.py", line 281, in gameLoop
    self.paint(self.canvas)

  File "C:\Users\Kim Donguk\Desktop\Game project\game_source\game.py", line 260, in paint
    self.canvas.delete(ALL)

  File "C:\Users\Kim Donguk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2508, in delete
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'delete') + args)

_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing a [mcve], but it looks like you're destroying things that you then try to use after they've been destroyed, like your canvas.

Comment: You edited, but that is not enough. You should check the link provided in the comment above. Your code uses the class `GalagaGame()` which you do not share. The exception is inherent to a `Canvas()` widget which is not used in the code you share.

Comment: short answer: you are trying to call a method on the canvas after destroying the canvas.